# Cant get into Advanced Boot Options on Acer with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a laptop (**Acer 5742**) which suddenly is refusing to boot into windows. It gives me the error: **0xc00000e9**.
I have googled it and tried many solutions to this problem.

My only hope to be able to fix it without having to do a format and reinstall is probably to boot windows in safe mode and then do a system restore.

However, I cant seem to get into the advanced boot options menu.

What Ive tried from looking at other solutions: **F5, F8 and Alt+F10**

I have also tried this without any luck:
[F8 not showing "Advanced Boot Options" on a Windows 7 PC](https://superuser.com/questions/346309/f8-not-showing-advanced-boot-options-on-a-windows-7-pc)

Can any of you help me out with this problem?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/212437/hard-disk-fail, http://superuser.com/questions/403028/status-0xc00000e9, http://superuser.com/questions/409872/hdd-cannot-be-booted-from

Comment: @techie007 None of these help. Any other suggestions?